# ValueError when trying to compress text

Tags: python

I have been given a task to develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list. I have done the code but when I run it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 11, in <module>
    PositionOfWords = list2.index(word)
ValueError: Substring not found
```

Here is my code:

```
UserSentence = input("enter sentence:").lower()
words = UserSentence.split()
PositionOfWords = [words]
list1 = []
list2 = ""

for word in words:
    if PositionOfWords not in list1:
        list1.append(PositionOfWords)
    for word in words:
        PositionOfWords = list2.index(word)
        list2+=string(PositionOfWords+int("1"))
        list2 +=("")
    list1str += ";".join(list)
file = open ("filename.txt","w")
file.write
file.write(sentence)
file.write(list1str)
file.write(list2)
file = open ("filename.txt", "r")
print (file.read())
file.close
```

Comment: The error ist obvious. `list2` is empty, so you can't get any index of any word. You really wrote this on your own??

Comment: yeah i did the thing is im not a good programmer thanks anyway

Comment: `.index` retrieves the index of an element in a list (or a string, but you're attempting to use it as though the target is a list), and your `list2` is empty: `list2 = ""`. Are you sure you didn't mean `list1.index(word)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so rather than fixing your code, I took the liberty to re-write it.
Hopefully I got the logic right.

Also, please do not use *file* as a variable, as its built-in variable within python. it would create issues and also not a good practice.

Here's high-level Pseudo-code

- Read user input
- convert to list of strings  as UserSentence
- read this list and append to list of unique words from input sentence
  as PositionOfWords
- now go through list of strings for user input and construct a string
  newSentence with its index position from PositionOfWords
- write UserSentence to file
- write PositionOfWords to file
- write newSentence to file

Here's working code:

```
UserSentence = input("enter sentence:").lower().split()
#list to store unique words
PositionOfWords = []

newSentence = ''  #new sentence


#Read each word in UserSentence and process
for word in UserSentence:
    if word not in PositionOfWords:
        PositionOfWords.append(word)

#Once we have unique words list, Lets get their positions in given sentence
for word in UserSentence:
    #get position of word  append to new sentence
    newSentence += str(PositionOfWords.index(word))

newSentence = ' '.join(newSentence)

myfile = open ("filename.txt","w")
myfile.writelines('UserSentence = {} '.format(UserSentence))
myfile.writelines('\n')
myfile.writelines('PositionOfWords = {} '.format(PositionOfWords))
myfile.writelines('\n')
myfile.writelines('newSentence = {} '.format(newSentence))
myfile.close()

print PositionOfWords
print newSentence
```

File Output:

> UserSentence = ['this', 'is', 'repeating', 'sentence', 'this', 'is', 'repeating', 'sentence']
>   PositionOfWords = ['this', 'is', 'repeating', 'sentence']
>   newSentence = 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3